# Perl LWP - need get timings: DNS resolving time, ssl connect, etc

Tags: perl, lwp

I am using LWP to check website accessibility for HTTPS.
But, sometimes there are delays of 3000 ms

```
sub get_url{
  my $url = shift;
  my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  $browser->timeout($alltimeout);
  
  eval {
      local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
      alarm $alltimeout;
      $response = $browser->get($url,
         'User-Agent' => 'CHECKER (Win98; U)',
         'Accept-Charset' => 'utf-8',
      );
      alarm 0;      
  };
  if ($@) {print "$@"; return "Timeout $alltimeout - error!"}
  if ($response->is_success){$resp[0]=200; return $response->content;}
    else {return "ERROR".$response->status_line}
}
```

i want to check separately: DNS resolving time, ssl connect time, etc for HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

LWP, and many other modules you'll use, aren't instrumented to produce this sort of tracing, and certainly not in any coherent or consistent fashion. You'd have to delve into the individual modules to provide your own hooks for this.

Do you see the same delays with other browsers, such as curl or wget?

Comment: I see delays in Perl. But, I check 1000 times an hour. 

Maybe there are other Perl modules for https?

Comment: You could try [Mojo::UserAgent](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients), but if you are checking thousands of times an hour, perhaps rate limiting is an issue.

Comment: Thanks. 
Can i check  timings (dns, ssl) in Mojo::UserAgent?

Comment: My answer applies to just about any Perl module that is not specifically made to benchmark web things. You need to find another tool for that.